nodejs mongoDB read document in local database
am trying to read data from local database at "startup_log" collection with NodeJS,
i running in command Prompt the "nodemone createdb.js", but nothings happened.
my code is below
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;  
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';  
const databasename = "local";// Database name  
MongoClient.connect(url).then((client) => {  
  
    const connect = client.db(databasename);  
  
    // Collection name  
    const collection = connect.collection("startup_log");  
  
     collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result.name);
        db.close();
      });
}).catch((err) => {  
    console.log(err.Message);  
}) 

can someone help me

Instead of creating a callback in the Array, store the doc that you have fetched from the db and then you can print them , one more thing while dealing with DB kinds of stuff we can use an asynchronous function to ensure the execution of the written functionality. I have corrected the code And pasted below kindly check it for your reference MATE!!...
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';
const databasename = "local";// Database name  
MongoClient.connect(url).then(async (client) => {

  console.log('DB CONNECTED')
  const connect = client.db(databasename);

  // Collection name  
  const collection = connect.collection("startup_log");

  const data = await collection.find({}).toArray();
  console.log(data);
  client.close();
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err.Message);
});


There are multiple way to implement this:
Solution-1: Your approach
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;  
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';  
const databasename = "local";// Database name  
MongoClient.connect(url).then(async (client) => {  
    const connect = client.db(databasename);  
    // Collection name  
    const collection = connect.collection("startup_log");  
  
    try { 
        const findResult = await collection.find({}).toArray();
        console.log('Found documents =>', findResult);
        client.close()
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof MongoServerError) {
            console.log(`Error worth logging: ${error}`); 
        }
        throw error; 
    }
}).catch((err) => {  
    console.log(err.Message);  
})

Solution-2: mongodb docs
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
// or as an es module:
// import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(url);

// Database Name
const dbName = 'local';

async function main() {
    // Use connect method to connect to the server
    await client.connect();
    console.log('Connected successfully to server');
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const collection = db.collection('startup_log');

    try {
        const findResult = await collection.find({}).toArray();
        console.log('Found documents =>', findResult);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof MongoServerError) {
            console.log(`Error worth logging: ${error}`); 
        }
        throw error; 
    }

    // the following code examples can be pasted here...
    return 'done.';
}

main()
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error)
    .finally(() => client.close());

Solution-3: Other approach
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");  
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';  
const client = new MongoClient(url);
// Database name  
const dbName = "local";

async function dbConnection() {
    await client.connect();
    console.log('Connected successfully to server');
    return client;
}

dbConnection()
    .then(async (client) => { 
        console.log('Trying to connect database');
        const connect = client.db(dbName);  
        // Collection name  
        const collection = connect.collection("startup_log"); 
        try { 
            const findResult = await collection.find({}).toArray();
            console.log('Found documents =>', findResult);
            return true;
        } catch (error) {
            if (error instanceof MongoServerError) {
                console.log(`Error worth logging: ${error}`); // special case for some reason
            }
            throw error; // still want to crash
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {  
        console.log('error: ', err.Message);  
    })
    .finally(() => client.close());

Where package.json should be:
{
  "name": "test_mongoo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node filename.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "mongodb": "^6.8.0"
  }
}

